# When does the suggested edit review count appear?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

So now that I surpassed the 2000 mark, I randomly get this suggested edit review count (16) to the right of my badges, to the left of review, but not always.

When does it appear? When does it disappear?

I can't figure out when it's there and when it's not. When I click the **review** link the number doesn't correspond with any of the queue sizes. And, it randomly disappears even when the queues still have entries. I kind of want to drop down to 1999 reputation just to make this feature go away.

[image: suggested edits]

Comment: It is the number of pending suggested edits at the time the page was loaded. It doesn't update.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238699/230506

Comment: @James, yes, I think that link does have the answers in it. Looks like it appears when there are 5 or more suggested edits. That, combined with Tim pointing out that it represents the queue size when the page loaded. It's just kind of confusing because SO's queue sizes change so rapidly. It's a kind of Heisenberg uncertainty principle in work here.

Comment: As you said, so much frequency and change, especially on SO, that immediate/live updates would use too much resource, so a bit of cache and delay is to be expected.

Comment: Yeah, understood. After being on SO sort of at the periphery for years I only recently got catapulted, sort of by chance it feels, due to popularity a couple of fairly short and not very difficult of my answers...and so now I am suddenly grappling with the review and edit privilege. It kind of feels like a curse to have more edit privileges.  I imagine I'm going to do about 50 reviews and lose my edit privileges due to down voting. Having the **suggested edits** button hovering there tempts me to go do reviews but I feel overwhelmed when I get there.

Comment: Given the fact you *have* concerns over doing a good or bad job, I imagine you will therefore do at least an average job, so I wouldn't worry and just do some. You're always going to be far better than robo-reviewers, and those who don't care like you do. Once you do a review, you can click browser back and see what others did (if no-one else has reviewed yet leave the tab open and refresh in a while). Then you can get an idea if you're on the right track. And there's always a "Skip" button for any you're unsure of :)

Comment: Oh, and don't worry so much about acting differently to others in reviews, more so if you are confident your decision was right based on XYZ. We're a huge bunch of folks with difference of opinion and rationales etc, so we're always going to disagree between us. I review here on MSE, and often scratch my head at some of the decisions from even high rep seasoned users. Sometimes I'll be wrong, sometimes them. That's why it takes reviews from a handful of users to hit a conclusion :)